Azure DocumentIntelligence Client KeyvaluePair option is readonly
When calling DocumentIntelligenceClient.AnalyzeDocumentAsync() , the 'options' parameter of type AnalyzeDocumentOptions cannot be used to set it's Features attribute (of type List<DocumentAnalysisFeature> ) as that property is readonly.
Creating a separate  List<DocumentAnalysisFeature> object does not help, as this latest package does not have a parameter for such.
How exactly then would one use the options for

QueryFields
Formulas
KeyValuePairs
if these attributes are readonly in the AnalyzeDocumentOptions class?

We are using the Azure.AI.DocumentIntelligence client v1.0.0 (release GA 2024-11-30) in C#.

KeyValuePairs if these attributes are readonly in the AnalyzeDocumentOptions class? yes it is readonly but can be modified in collection.



KeyValuePairs if these attributes are readonly in the  AnalyzeDocumentOptions  class?


Yes, you are right  Features property in AnalyzeDocumentOptions is readonly, which means you cannot assign to it directly (e.g., Features = {...}), but you can modify the collection.
Here is the sample code that you can modify in the collection using Azure.AI.DocumentIntelligence .NET SDK.
Code:
using Azure;
using Azure.AI.DocumentIntelligence;
using Azure.Core;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        string endpoint = "https://xxxx.cognitiveservices.azure.com/";
        string apiKey = "xxx";
        Uri documentUri = new Uri("file uri");

        var client = new DocumentIntelligenceClient(new Uri(endpoint), new AzureKeyCredential(apiKey));

        // Initialize options and add the desired features
        var options = new AnalyzeDocumentOptions("prebuilt-invoice", documentUri)
        {
            // Adding features such as Formulas and KeyValuePairs
            Features = { DocumentAnalysisFeature.Formulas, DocumentAnalysisFeature.KeyValuePairs }
        };

        // Perform document analysis
        var operation = await client.AnalyzeDocumentAsync(WaitUntil.Completed, options);
        AnalyzeResult result = operation.Value;

        // Iterate through the result
        foreach (DocumentPage page in result.Pages)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"----Detected information from page #{page.PageNumber}----");

            // Extract Formulas
            if (page.Formulas != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Detected {page.Formulas.Count} formulas.");
                foreach (var formula in page.Formulas)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Formula: {formula.Value}");
                    Console.WriteLine($"Kind: {formula.Kind}");
                    Console.WriteLine($"Confidence: {formula.Confidence}");
                    Console.WriteLine($"Bounding Polygon: {string.Join(", ", formula.Polygon)}");
                }
            }

            // Extract Key-Value Pairs
            var keyValuePairs = result.KeyValuePairs;
            if (keyValuePairs != null)
            {
                foreach (var kvp in keyValuePairs)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Key: {kvp.Key.Content}, Value: {kvp.Value.Content}");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Output:
  ----Detected information from page #1----
Detected 0 formulas.
----Detected information from page #2----
Detected 0 formulas.
----Detected information from page #3----
Detected 1 formulas.
Formula: A
Kind: inline
Confidence: 0.669
Bounding Polygon: 5.2334, 2.3327, 5.3419, 2.3327, 5.3419, 2.4411, 5.2334, 2.4411
----Detected information from page #4----
Detected 0 formulas.
 Key: Name:, Value: John Doe
 Key: Age:, Value: 30
 Key: Country:, Value: USA
 Key: City:, Value: New York
 Key: Occupation:, Value: Software Engineer
 Key: Hobby:, Value: Reading Books
 Key: Language:, Value: English
 Key: Favorite Color:, Value: Blue


Reference:
[QUERY] - How does one analyze a document with Features and QueryFields in Azure Document Intelligence 1.0.0? · Issue #47630 · Azure/azure-sdk-for-net by kinelski.
